# "slights on his personal appearance were, it seemed, as nothing to the danger he had spotted" meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "Are you out of your mind?" demanded Harry. "A plot to get this house? Are you actually as stupid as you look?"
>
> "Don't you dare -?" squealed Aunt Petunia, but again, Vernon waved her down: **slights on his personal appearance were, it seemed, as nothing to the danger he had spotted**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

What does the part in bold mean exactly? I think it draws a comparison. I'm also wondering why 'as' is used. Can we remove it? "*slights on his personal appearance were nothing to the danger he had spotted*" seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence can be taken to mean

> criticism of his personal appearance were, apparently, not important compared to the danger he had spotted

There is a [previous question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35054/meaning-of-as-in-as-nothing) which touches on the use of "*as nothing*"

You can leave the "as" out without changing the meaning, but "as nothing" is idiomatic English and gives slight emphasis to the comparison.

"as nothing" = "really nothing [insignificant] compared to"